# How to achieve sentence level proximity in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, information-retrieval, whoosh

Lets say I have bunch of documents and each document is list of sentences.

Now when I enter a query, the words in the query which are exactly in a single sentence (out of order) should rank higher.

So the thing is if all keywords exist in a sentence then rank higher instead of fining keywords in different sentences.